# Using VCR with Cucumber via tags

Tags: testing, cucumber, bdd, vcr

I have some Cucumber features which need to interact with the Google Maps Routing API. I'm trying to stub out these interactions using [VCR](https://github.com/myronmarston/vcr).

I have added a VCR tag to my features like so:

```
@google_routing_api @javascript
Scenario: Creating a bus
  Given I am on the buses page
  When I follow "Get Started Now"
```

And then added my VCR configuration in `features/support/vcr.rb`

```
require 'vcr'

VCR.config do |c|
  # INFO: This is relative to the Rails.root
  c.cassette_library_dir = 'features/fixtures/vcr_cassettes'
  c.stub_with :fakeweb
end

# INFO: https://github.com/myronmarston/vcr/wiki/Usage-with-Cucumber
VCR.cucumber_tags do |t|
  t.tag '@google_routing_api'
end
```

But when I run my cukes, I am told..

```
Real HTTP connections are disabled. Unregistered request: GET http://127.0.0.1:54181/__identify__
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to set VCR to [ignore localhost requests](https://www.relishapp.com/myronmarston/vcr/v/1-6-0/docs/configuration/ignore-localhost). Otherwise, when capybara tries to request any page from your website, VCR will block it.

Add `c.ignore_localhost = true` to your VCR config block.

```
VCR.config do |c|
  c.cassette_library_dir = 'features/fixtures/vcr_cassettes'
  c.stub_with :fakeweb
  c.ignore_localhost = true
end
```

Comment: FWIW, the problem (and the solution) has nothing to do with cucumber.  It has everything to do with capybara and the fact that it boots your app and makes requests to it when you use a javascript driver.  You'd have the same problem if you used capybara with Test::Unit or RSpec.